# Pandas optimize performance loc function

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataset with > 50000 rows. Some of the data is missing, for that I'm using a nested loop and loc function to fill in the missing values.

Dataset
[image]

So what I'm doing basically is for the second row, I'll find the mean of all the rating for **usa** and mean for all rating for **1**, divide by 2 and use it as rating. In this case it will be (3.25).
Code I've written:

```
    for i in data[data.rate.isna()]['name']:
      for j in data.location.unique():
        data.loc[(data.rate.isna()) & (data.name == i) & (data.location == j), rate] = (data[data.name == i].rate.mean() + data[data.location == j].mean())/2
```

Is there any way to optimize this?
This takes a lot of time, I found a finction called at but it uses indexes not conditions, np.where but how will it fit in this case (takes a lot of time or gives me error)?

Comment: Please add a target data.

Comment: I've added a sample. Rating column is rate in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate the mean of location and name first separately. then join the origin dataframe.

```
mean_location = df.groupby('location')['rating'].mean().rename('rating_location')
mean_name = df.groupby('name')['rating'].mean().rename('rating_name')

df = (df.join(mean_location, on='location')
        .join(mean_name, on='name'))

print(df)

       name  rating location  rating_location  rating_name
    0     1     3.0       uk              3.0          3.5
    1     1     NaN      usa              3.0          3.5
    2     2     4.0      usa              3.0          4.0
    3     4     2.0      usa              3.0          2.0
    4     1     4.0   france              4.0          3.5


df['reating_fill'] = (df['rating_location'] + df['rating_name'])/2
# use combine_first to fill na
df['rating'] = df['rating'].combine_first(df['reating_fill'])
```

result:

```
df

       name  rating location  rating_location  rating_name  reating_fill
    0     1    3.00       uk              3.0          3.5          3.25
    1     1    3.25      usa              3.0          3.5          3.25
    2     2    4.00      usa              3.0          4.0          3.50
    3     4    2.00      usa              3.0          2.0          2.50
    4     1    4.00   france              4.0          3.5          3.75
```

Comment: This works fine as long as there's a value for each name.
In the actual dataset for some names, I don't have any value so when you do this.. rating_name                  45632 non-null  float64
rating_location              51624 non-null  float64
rating_fill                  45632 non-null  float64
So ultimately the problem isn't solved. ^^

Comment: It is very fast though.
data['rating_name'].fillna(0, inplace=True). Did this, thanks for your answer.